# Facebook Cordova Plugin - TFS file path too long issue in get latest

Tags: build, cordova-plugins

We are using "Facebook Cordova Plugin" and I get following error when trying to get latest,
I get this error for several files.

Error:

> TF400889: The following path contains more than the allowed 259
>   characters: C:\TFSBuilds\1\Project1\Project1 Dev
>   Build\src\Project1.Mobile\Project1_ww\platforms\ios\Project1_ww\Plugins\com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect\FacebookSDK.framework\Versions\A\Resources\FBUserSettingsViewResources.bundle\Contents\Resources\en.lproj\Localizable.strings.
>   Specify a shorter path.

What options do I have? Has anyone encountered similar issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a client side path limitation with Team Foundation Server. You can workaround this issue by trying below options.

- Mapping the build definition to shorter build agent path. Go
  to Source Settings tab in build definition, here shorten the path
  configured for Build Agent folder.
- Make sure that Build Agent working directory also using the short
  path. You can check this from Build Menu --> Manage Build Controllers
  --> Select the relevant build agents and click properties. Here the path configured for working directory should not be too long.